# AngularJS data-binding vs KnockoutJS data-binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, knockout.js

For some internal reasons I needed to convert my AngularJS app to KnockoutJS, so recently I started to play around with Knockout.

First thing I noticed was that the binding with Angular was immediate, like char-by-char: http://jsfiddle.net/anvarik/3cnV9/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>First Name: {{first}}</p>
    <p>Last Name: {{second}}</p>

    <p>First Name: <input ng-model="first" /> </p>
    <p>Last Name: <input ng-model="second" /> </p>
</div>
```

Knockout on the other hand, takes the whole input and binds at the end: http://jsfiddle.net/anvarik/CxBy9/

```
<div>
    <p>First Name: <strong data-bind="text:firstName"></strong></p>
    <p>Last Name: <strong data-bind="text:lastName"></strong></p>

    <p>First Name: <input data-bind="value:firstName"/> </p>
    <p>Last Name: <input data-bind="value:lastName"/> </p>
</div>
```

I will be glad if someone can explain me the reasoning behind it. I want to make the binding in Knockout as it was in Angular, how to accomplish that?

Comment: You need to add one more option (valueUpdate option) in knockout to have the same behaviour as in angular. Example: <input data-bind="value: someValue, **valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'**" />
By default, value is updated at 'change' event. See doc at: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

Comment: thanks a lot, if you want go for an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add one more option (valueUpdate option) in knockout to have the same behaviour as in angular. Example:

```
<input data-bind="value: someValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

By default, value is updated at 'change' event. See doc at: [knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html)